# dirichlet process - formula explanatation

Tags: self-study, dirichlet-distribution, dirichlet-process

i am self-studying the Dirichlet process, from among others http://www.stat.ubc.ca/~bouchard/courses/stat547-sp2011/notes-part2.pdf, and struggling with the following basic question:

I understand the Dirichlet distribution to gives us a vector of probabilities (e.g. 0.1,0.4,0.2,0.1 if one has 4 classes). i would hence have assumed, in the text per below, that only $$(G(A_1)/\sum^k_{i}(G_{A_i}), G(A_2)/\sum^k_{i}(G_{A_i},....)$$ would be dirichlet distributed (where k is the number of classes). Put differently, i would have expected that would have to normalize the vector by the sum over $G(A)$ to get to probabilities between 0 and 1. please let me know where i am wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

$\Omega$ is partitioned into $K$ disjoint partitions $(A_1,\ldots,A_K)$ and $G(\Omega) = \sum_{k=1}^{K}A_k = 1$. Thus you don't need to normalize. It is already a probability vector.

Another note, your example of a draw from a  Dirichlet distribution is wrong. Draws from Dirichlet distribution are on a probability simplex.

if $(\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_K) \sim Dir(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_K)$, then $\sum_{k=1}^K \theta_k = 1$.